# Как сверстать сетку с «выпавшими», пустыми элементами?

Tags: css3, grid, css-grid

Коллеги, прошу вас помочь мне с идеей как сверстать сетку, у которой есть пустые ячейки без контента.

САБЖ:
Вот макет секции. Секция будет заполняться из админ панели. Т.е. все ячейки по порядку. Т.е. необходим алгоритм без прозрачности. Чтобы ячейка была именно "сдвинута" или "выпала"
Квадраты с крестами - пустые.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что это будет grid
Я понимаю, что с помощью grid-area

ПРОБЛЕМА
У меня вопрос об Автоматическом размещении ячеек, чтобы не прописывать КАЖДОЙ ее координаты в сетке.
Также хотелось бы иметь адаптер.
На мобе все ячейки встанут друг под друга.

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: а может ну его грид? обычный флекс с классами для пустых ячеек, по которому прятать?

Comment: @Arbery Дык... Флекс сдвинет Остальные ячейки на место исчезнувших.(((((

Comment: opacity: 0; pointer-events:none  или visibility: hidden;

Comment: @Arbery, простите, не уточнила. 
Этот макет будет заполняться из админ панели. Следовательно я контентщик будет заливать имиджи по порядку. Не пропуская. Его не интересует, как и что у него под капотом.
Ваше предложение приведет к тому, что N-й загруженный имидж будет не виден.. Так не робит.(((

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid { grid-auto-flow: row dense }
.grid > :nth-child(5n) { grid-column-start: span 2 }
```

Например: каждый 5-й элемент занимает две колонки в сетке, при этом его ширина может быть заданной равной ширине колонок. Таким образом, появляется пустая область справа вместо соседней карточки.

Минусы такого подхода: 1)первые ячейки в ряду никогда не будут пустыми (если это важно). 2) Визуальная последовательность карточек, заданная в grid-auto-flow (dense: алгоритм «плотной» упаковки) может отличаться от последовательности элементов в DOM

**Подразумеваю, что карточек может быть непредсказуемо много, а на картинке в вопросе лишь частный случай*

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  min-height: 12rem;
}

.item:nth-child(1),
.item:nth-child(6),
.item:nth-child(12) {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .items {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
  .item:nth-child(1),
  .item:nth-child(6),
  .item:nth-child(12) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>

  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>

  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>

  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну значит, раз html-менять нельзя и порядок пустых ячеек стабилен - использовать `grid-column-start`, считать какую колонку должна занимать ячейка и назначать ей значение +1. Для мобилок - переназначить порядок.

```css
.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ff0;
  min-height: 70px;
}
.item:nth-child(6) {
  background: #f0f;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
.item:nth-child(12) {
  background: #f0f;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>

  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>

  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>

  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
</div>
```